# Angular Material Progress Spinner not animated

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to add an indeterminate spinner from Angular Material. I checked the official stack blitz example https://stackblitz.com/angular/nkabnxaenep. I compared the package jsons and cant find any differences. a am ahead a few minor versions. The determinate mode works though...
I imported the correct module and there are no errors at runtime.

```
<mat-spinner mode="indeterminate"></mat-spinner>
```

[image: not working spinner image]

Any ideas? Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Did you import the `BrowserAnimationsModule` into your AppModule?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper no I didnt. I didnt know that existed. I didn't see anything about that in the docs. It fixed it thx. If you create an answer ill accept that

Comment: Alright, I'll also link to the documentation that mentions it to enrich the answer a bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enable the animations of Angular Material you have to import the `BrowserAnimationsModule` into your `AppModule` as mentioned in the 3rd step of the [getting started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#install-angular-material).

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    // NoopAnimationsModule,
    ...
```

**Note:** make sure to remove the `NoopAnimationsModule` from your project as well.

**Update**: The recommended way to install Angular Material nowadays is with `ng add @angular/material`, which should already set this up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Robin De Schepper suggested, the solution is to add **BrowserAnimationsModule** to app.module.ts

like this:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    // NoopAnimationsModule,
    ...
```

NOTE: For the newer versions of Angular, if you have **NoopAnimationsModule** in your imports array, you must comment/remove it.

Comment: Thanks, if it's OK with you I'll include your example in my answer